# Differences between normal function and expression function

Tags: kotlin

We already know all functions in Kotlin are types, so if have this function:

```
    fun p() : Unit 
{
    println("Hello P")
}
```

This is just a function that have no parameter and return a Unit, so i can declare another function that do the same thing

```
fun y() : () -> Unit = 
{
    println("Hello Y")

}
```

But there are different results when i run these functions

```
p() //-->  will print out "Hello P"

y() //--> doesn't print out anything
```

But if i call y() this way:

```
y()() //--> will print out "Hello Y"
```

Could you please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We already know all functions in Kotlin are types

This is not true. There are function types, instances of function types, and function declarations. This is a declaration of a function whose return type is `Unit`:

```
fun p() : Unit 
{
    println("Hello P")
}
```

This is a function type:

```
() -> Unit
```

This is a declaration of a function whose return type is the function type `() -> Unit`:

```
fun y() : () -> Unit = 
{
    println("Hello Y")
}
```

Whereas invoking `p()` executes the print statement, invoking `y()` just returns a function instance which, when invoked, will execute the print statement:

```
y()()
```

Structurally, a function declaration is very similar to the declaration of a property with a function type:

```
val x: () -> Unit = 
{
    println("Hello X")
}
```

Syntactically you can use it the same way:

```
x()
```

You can also pass it to another function:

```
fun higherOrderFun(block: () -> Unit) [
    println("higher order")
    block()
}

higherOrderFun(x)
```

But you can't do the same with a function declaration:

```
higherOrderFun(p) // Compiler error
```

This is because a function declaration isn't a "thing" you can pass around, it's just a declaration of executable code.

You can also create an instance of function type from a function declaration:

```
::p
```

This is now equivalent to `x`. In fact, you can also write

```
val x = ::p
```

and now you have an instance `x` that does nothing but immediately call `p()` and return its value.

While there is a strong formal symmetry between function declarations and function instances, and there are even languages that only have the latter (e.g., JavaScript or LISP), the former are better for performance and memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of your example

```
fun y() : () -> Unit = 
{
    println("Hello Y")

}
```

is actually a function type `()->Unit`, so when you call it, this anonymous function is being returned without calling it. You can call it like this:

```
y()()
```

What you can do instead is creating a variable holding this [function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html):

```
val y = { println("Hello Y") }
```

And simply call it like this: `y()`

Answer (score 1):

We can slightly rewrite the definitions of `p` and `y` without changing their meaning:

```
fun p() {
    println( "Hello p")
}

fun y() = {
    println( "Hello y")
}
```

Note that the syntax is almost identical ( `=` makes all the difference ) which is a bit unfortunate since `p` and `y` are quite different beasts.

- `fun p` is a function declaration. `p` accepts no parameters and returns Unit
- `fun y` is a function declaration. `y` accepts no parameters and returns a **function** whose type is () -> Unit

Because a call to `y()` returns a function, you need to invoke **that** function to get it to print: `y()()`

All of the above doesn't say much about the type of `p` and `y` themselves - only that they **return** certain types:

- the actual type of `p` is `KFunction0< Unit >`
- the actual type of `y` is `KFunction0< () -> Unit >`

If you want to play with this a bit more :-)  consider:

```
fun yy() = {
    ::p
}
```

You can verify that `yy()()()` prints `hello p` and its type is `KFunction0<()->KFunction0<Unit>>`